# Javascript function does not work :/

Tags: javascript, html, expand

This piece of code is trying to make an expander button. I just copy paste it from jsfiddle. Why is it good on jsfiddle but does not work on my browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" id="button-1" value="(click here for more information)"><br>
<p id="special1">
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</p>

<script>
  alert(0);
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var count = 0;
        alert(1);

      $("#special1").hide();

      $("#button-1").click(function(){
          count++;
          if(count % 2 != 0){
            $("#special1").show();
          }else{
              $("#special1").hide();
          }
      })
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle may be loading jQuery for you... you need to make sure you are loading too.

Comment: Have you attached the jQuery library? And check your browser's console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded jQuery anywhere in your page. jsFiddle loads it for you.

Add a script tag for it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you look in the browser's error console, it is likely saying that `undefined` is not a function because `$` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Well, how to load that jQuery thing?

Comment: @user3780872: You can learn about that by reading the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: FYI, JQuery is a library of [functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) that are defined to make common tasks easier. You can't use those functions without defining them, which is why you need the library included.

Answer (score 0):

The script is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but you are not including it on the page. Try adding `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` before your `<script>` tag.